# Creating a label dataset from a segmented image using Python

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, scikit-image

I've labeled an image to produce a numpy array with labels e.g.

```
array([[0, 1, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ..., 
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [2, 2, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [2, 2, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)}
```

what is the most efficient way to turn this into the dataset:

```
x-coord | y-coord | label 
-------------------------
0       | 0       | 0
0       | 1       | 1
0       | 2       | 0
...
1024    | 0       | 2
1024    | 1       | 2
```

etc.

I don't mind what the output format is but I expect a dictionary would be most convenient.

This is my current *slow* code that iterates through coordinates of the image:

```
(x, y) = img.shape
for x1, x2 in np.ndindex((x, y)):
    data[(x1, x2)] = img[x1, x2]
```

The reason I'm doing this is that I would like to add other features to an array for each pixel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`np.meshgrid`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) and [`np.vstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) to create a `Nx3` numpy array having a similar format as stated as  desired in a vectorized manner, like so -

```
In [103]: img
Out[103]: 
array([[0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
       [2, 1, 1, 0, 2]])

In [104]: M,N = img.shape

In [105]: Y,X = np.meshgrid(np.arange(N),np.arange(M))

In [106]: np.vstack((X,Y,img)).reshape(3,-1).T
Out[106]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [0, 2, 1],
       [0, 3, 0],
       [0, 4, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 0],
       [1, 3, 0],
       [1, 4, 1],
       [2, 0, 1],
       [2, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 1],
       [2, 3, 1],
       [2, 4, 2],
       [3, 0, 2],
       [3, 1, 1],
       [3, 2, 1],
       [3, 3, 0],
       [3, 4, 2]])
```

Comment: What is the matrix `A` here?

Comment: @kungfujam Sorry, that was a typo. Check out the edits.